# Python converting xml to csv, how can I add quotation marks to my csv file?

Tags: python, xml, csv

The code parses through all the xml files in my folder and puts it all into one csv file. However I would like to add quotes and not sure how to go about doing that.

output:

```
image,width,height,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax,name
image1.png,416,416,Dog,1995,848,2155,1075
```

What I actually want:

```
"image","width","height","xmin","ymin","xmax","ymax","name"
"image1.png",416,416,1995,848,2155,1075,"Dog"
```

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def xml_to_csv(path):
    xml_list = []
    print(path)
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(member[4][3].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['image', 'width', 'height', 'name', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df


def main():
    for folder in ['train']:
        image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), ('images/' + folder))
        xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
        xml_df.to_csv(('images/' + folder + '_labels.csv'), index=None)
        print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')


main()
```

Comment: Use `'\"image\"'` instead?

Comment: @rdas Ah thank you, however that gives me """image" instead of "image"

Comment: Do note, since Pandas 1.3.0, [`read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) has been added to build data frames from flat XML files which yours appear to be.

Answer (score 0):

Add `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`.  Demo:

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

column_name = ['image', 'width', 'height', 'name', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
df = pd.DataFrame([["image1.png",416,416,1995,848,2155,1075,"Dog"]],columns=column_name)

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Output:

```
"image","width","height","name","xmin","ymin","xmax","ymax"
"image1.png",416,416,1995,848,2155,1075,"Dog"
```